# Using input data to form a date for the output data in a DMN Camunda rule

Tags: camunda, bpmn, rule-engine, dmn

I am currently using DMN for a task. This task basically checks a given month and day, depending on the input will create a specific date for the output variable. My issue is the output date is dependant on the input year i.e if the input was 2022/04/01, then my output would be 2022-02-30 (Similar for 2019, output would be 2019). I cannot figure out how I can use the input variable for year as the year in the output ? Or maybe this is not possible ?

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In definedDate you could use the `string join` function, e.g.: `date and time(string join ([string(YEAR), "09-22T00:00:00"], "-"))`

**Edit:**

`string join` seems not to be available in Camunda DMN, however it is available in other DMN Tools (see [here](https://kiegroup.github.io/dmn-feel-handbook/#string-join-list)).